# Get only the content of folder with glob

Tags: gulp, glob

I'm currently trying to copy some files using gulp. 
To do this, I need to use a `glob` pattern to explain which files to copy.

I have a `dist`folder containing what i need, but every time I copy it, I get the `dist` folder copied as well.

It looks something like this.

```
gulp.src('./dist/**')
```

can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd also set your destination, it will work as expected:

```
gulp.task('distcopy', function() {
  return gulp.src('dist/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('foo'));
});
```

Now, `index.html` in `dist/` will be copied to `foo/index.html`.